# If $A_{2\times 4}D_{4\times 2}=I_2$,is it possible that $C_{4\times 2}A=I_4$

Tags: linear-algebra

$A=\left[\begin{matrix}1&1&1&0\\0&1&1&1\end{matrix}\right]$

Construct a $4\times 2$ matrix D using only $1,0$ as entries, such that $AD=I_2$.  Is it possible that $CA=I_4$ for some $4\times 2$ matrix C?

I got $D=\left[\begin{matrix}1&0\\-1&1\\1&-1\\0&1\end{matrix}\right]$, don't have any idea how to prove the second part.

Comment: Hint: What is the largest possible rank of a product of matrices given the ranks of each matrix?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft,this question is before the rank concept,use just the matrix multiplication,inverse, elementary matrices etc

Comment: Ok, can you find a non-zero vector $v$ such that $Av = 0$?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft,ok I found (-2,1,1,-2)

Comment: Your matrix $D$ has entries equal to $-1$, which is not allowed according to your problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly try it. Consider
$$
C=\begin{pmatrix}c_{11} & c_{12}\\c_{21}&c_{22}\\c_{31}&c_{32}\\c_{41}&c_{42}\end{pmatrix}.
$$
From $CA=I_4$ you get
$$
\begin{pmatrix}c_{11}&c_{11}+c_{12}&c_{11}+c_{12}&c_{12}\\
c_{21}&c_{21}+c_{22}&c_{21}+c_{22}&c_{22}\\c_{31}&c_{31}+c_{32}&c_{31}+c_{32}&c_{32}\\
c_{41}&c_{41}+c_{42}&c_{41}+c_{42}&c_{42}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}.
$$
From the first row you get already a contradiction, since
$$
c_{11}=1\\
c_{11}+c_{12}=0\\
c_{12}=0
$$
is not solvable. Therefore you can't find $C$ such that $CA=I_4$ even if you could use arbitrary entries.

Comment: Cool,this helps,thanx

Comment: Your welcome. But I just realized that your answer $D$ is not correct since the entries of $D$ should be only $0$ or $1$. Such a $D$ exists. You could also try the same ansatz as in my answer to get your $D$ with entries $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 1):

When you right-multiply a matrix by another matrix, each column of the product is a linear combination of the columns of the left-hand matrix with coefficients given by the entries in the corresponding column of the right-hand matrix. Examining the columns of $A$, we find that its first and last columns are exactly what we want, so $$D=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\\0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$ This is a generally useful technique to know: to pick out the $j$th column of a matrix, right-multiply it by the $j$th column of the identity.

Similarly, left-multiplying a matrix by another produces linear combinations of its *rows*. Looking at just the first row of $I_4$, is there any linear combination of the rows of $A$ that can produce $(1,0,0,0)$? No. The only way to get a zero in the last column is to multiply the second row by zero, but then there’s no way to get zeros in the second and third columns while keeping the first non-zero.